# How to run multiple processes in node?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, docker, pm2

I am building a web application and would like to run 3 different commands.

- run mongodb
- Run react-scripts to build/watch react app.
- Run express server.

I can do this individually in different terminal sessions, but would it be possible to run these with 1 command using something such as pm2? (I know it's only meant for production usecase but for this is it overkill?) Or would something like a docker container work?

Sorry if this is an awful question. But I am at a loss at what I should actually be looking for!

Thanks,

Comment: [concurrently](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently#readme), but the question is offtopic

Comment: why do you not deploy multiple docker container over docker-compose? one for mongodb, one for react and one for nodejs?